# ORTools-VRP starts-ends returns a horrible solution

Tags: or-tools, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing

I referred to the code from [the link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/notebook/constraint_solver/vrp_starts_ends.ipynb?hl=zh-tw#scrollTo=code) and modified it a little bit so as to fit my problem.

Here's the description of my problem:

- There's only one vehicle, and it starts from point 0 (row 0/col 0) and ends at the last point (last row/last col).
- The cost matrix is asymmetric. (Note: The cost matrix is the travel time matrix by calling the OSRM API and then adjusting it by conducting the XGBoost regression)
- Find the shortest path to this known o-d pair.

And here's my code:

```py
def vrpRouting(timeMatx):
    data = {}
    data['costMatx'] = timeMatx
    data["num_vehicles"] = 1
    data["starts"] = [0]
    data["ends"] = [timeMatx.shape[0]-1]

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data["costMatx"]), data["num_vehicles"], data["starts"], data["ends"]
    )

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data["costMatx"][from_node][to_node]

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return timeMatx[from_node][to_node]
    
    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = "Distance"
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        86400,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name,
    )
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    index = routing.Start(0)
    orderList = [index]
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        orderList.append(index)

    return orderList
```

Input:

```py
timeMatx = array([[   0.      ,  605.24976 ,  269.00424 ,  606.7239  ,  295.72632 ,
                    701.6189  ,  269.7843  ,  514.0885  ,  507.23184 ,  544.19366 ,
                    226.32301 ,  441.45337 ,  613.2007  ,  606.7652  ,  593.4828  ,
                    414.8909  ,  155.63597 ,  565.78534 ,  298.49384 ,  491.65146 ,
                    52.440372,  484.62408 ,  374.28607 ,  685.8375  , 2165.6511  ,
                    825.4935  ],
                  [ 561.3975  ,    0.      ,  231.96214 ,  417.78793 ,  256.68472 ,
                    603.73035 ,  235.05937 ,  271.1455  ,  264.71735 ,  195.92427 ,
                    327.4776  ,  281.9526  ,  252.85829 ,  274.38208 ,  506.42474 ,
                    294.85602 ,  501.11224 ,  573.43286 ,  298.6754  ,  287.14642 ,
                    544.6249  ,  290.71954 ,  169.4396  ,  601.56433 , 1970.7639  ,
                    715.9111  ],
                  [ 262.27753 ,  323.74512 ,    0.      ,  503.0027  ,   48.66478 ,
                    556.1962  ,   49.444817,  292.84494 ,  306.4768  ,  365.8359  ,
                    51.76648 ,  290.83154 ,  485.11664 ,  462.46436 ,  432.70767 ,
                    236.12527 ,  197.15515 ,  540.28687 ,  301.12393 ,  329.84088 ,
                    276.75488 ,  329.84088 ,  215.01988 ,  553.1245  , 2215.9258  ,
                    668.996   ],
                  [ 676.66907 ,  440.7867  ,  538.61066 ,    0.      ,  523.7939  ,
                    328.48447 ,  571.5865  ,  392.6493  ,  390.994   ,  324.9568  ,
                    552.6026  ,  417.04404 ,  380.0602  ,  245.07535 ,  259.8233  ,
                    433.95746 ,  585.4867  ,  520.9353  ,  466.26447 ,  339.55667 ,
                    678.39624 ,  341.70975 ,  375.12747 ,  330.96844 , 2014.8074  ,
                    307.0386  ],
                  [ 279.03555 ,  312.55005 ,   48.66478 ,  491.4429  ,    0.      ,
                    545.7762  ,   49.444817,  267.90707 ,  298.87366 ,  361.43207 ,
                    62.489613,  284.3184  ,  456.6484  ,  462.51218 ,  418.38113 ,
                    224.31155 ,  186.10187 ,  532.77765 ,  280.48578 ,  329.84088 ,
                    286.0367  ,  321.64236 ,  199.83817 ,  546.7755  , 2025.4688  ,
                    632.142   ],
                  [ 727.03754 ,  595.5355  ,  610.61475 ,  297.4268  ,  605.13983 ,
                      0.      ,  615.9515  ,  438.4176  ,  471.41455 ,  483.88916 ,
                    699.1968  ,  489.25296 ,  553.45984 ,  409.81995 ,  314.77545 ,
                    467.4864  ,  659.3457  ,  383.023   ,  513.4552  ,  449.91113 ,
                    708.2596  ,  445.44595 ,  547.36676 ,   80.06507 , 2080.5547  ,
                    262.19095 ],
                  [ 257.08786 ,  326.2468  ,   51.166454,  488.04865 ,   51.166454,
                    586.5719  ,    0.      ,  291.75586 ,  309.40366 ,  360.60843 ,
                    52.762993,  289.2958  ,  465.60294 ,  463.53494 ,  413.9559  ,
                    241.64075 ,  198.96646 ,  512.3829  ,  291.21436 ,  326.0583  ,
                    270.51175 ,  319.29498 ,  223.7703  ,  566.83795 , 2215.1855  ,
                    662.5635  ],
                  [ 459.82492 ,  286.65698 ,  306.26852 ,  388.16956 ,  324.50848 ,
                    472.96484 ,  331.41495 ,    0.      ,  105.842026,  179.01134 ,
                    380.34143 ,  152.53131 ,  305.39743 ,  291.39746 ,  317.27963 ,
                    189.02483 ,  332.37558 ,  460.87854 ,  216.90073 ,   73.08488 ,
                    448.9391  ,   69.51257 ,  261.15314 ,  472.89905 , 2168.003   ,
                    588.8121  ],
                  [ 448.00867 ,  317.68057 ,  249.61453 ,  448.0973  ,  256.79227 ,
                    484.4628  ,  257.06888 ,  150.32164 ,    0.      ,  224.1563  ,
                    305.67023 ,   57.057663,  347.53983 ,  321.38745 ,  304.5325  ,
                    93.02085 ,  312.1978  ,  438.9198  ,  191.96974 ,  201.89294 ,
                    426.3994  ,  201.87694 ,  254.11345 ,  483.98294 , 2298.2432  ,
                    592.0609  ],
                  [ 555.53796 ,  220.56247 ,  410.68362 ,  430.04636 ,  391.3362  ,
                    581.43414 ,  420.44113 ,  285.7975  ,  285.53186 ,    0.      ,
                    483.14706 ,  305.77493 ,  166.89928 ,  265.15802 ,  505.59888 ,
                    327.89725 ,  545.64014 ,  549.73016 ,  365.22986 ,  317.2754  ,
                    541.4608  ,  304.20532 ,  276.38202 ,  576.97864 , 2080.0095  ,
                    580.7666  ],
                  [ 226.56038 ,  378.07886 ,   56.35862 ,  519.5915  ,   71.37685 ,
                    632.35425 ,   55.63349 ,  330.9645  ,  327.59625 ,  416.49722 ,
                      0.      ,  316.1576  ,  485.64777 ,  526.60693 ,  506.71664 ,
                    280.86526 ,  230.70573 ,  550.1051  ,  331.00058 ,  360.97076 ,
                    237.093   ,  354.3738  ,  258.68503 ,  583.74426 , 1903.4921  ,
                    751.7908  ],
                  [ 458.76953 ,  301.67664 ,  263.1459  ,  450.9532  ,  250.61711 ,
                    493.19943 ,  261.45465 ,  157.58664 ,   57.495247,  214.8607  ,
                    313.91885 ,    0.      ,  346.0988  ,  340.1446  ,  334.08752 ,
                    63.607277,  342.14474 ,  457.31595 ,  231.61456 ,  209.15794 ,
                    462.25943 ,  203.73096 ,  223.95009 ,  506.00223 , 2350.5847  ,
                    577.3593  ],
                  [ 642.9194  ,  291.66708 ,  511.38297 ,  355.97083 ,  459.01636 ,
                    561.35596 ,  498.29596 ,  356.08563 ,  353.01437 ,  186.48058 ,
                    519.45703 ,  374.19904 ,    0.      ,  152.57288 ,  519.08777 ,
                    371.75195 ,  538.47186 ,  663.63617 ,  445.79474 ,  400.12662 ,
                    632.9558  ,  384.0962  ,  316.19202 ,  563.8031  , 1911.8192  ,
                    492.3857  ],
                  [ 623.09015 ,  297.91776 ,  451.68054 ,  281.79025 ,  447.24365 ,
                    444.21805 ,  444.50677 ,  321.42468 ,  320.20535 ,  206.25587 ,
                    527.1237  ,  343.518   ,  148.0402  ,    0.      ,  363.97754 ,
                    352.02362 ,  537.3169  ,  577.52057 ,  412.57935 ,  299.2037  ,
                    627.4473  ,  277.2091  ,  291.3151  ,  452.99948 , 2149.2     ,
                    442.72867 ],
                  [ 579.5865  ,  490.6468  ,  520.3644  ,  279.6822  ,  503.1384  ,
                    309.12106 ,  507.2774  ,  303.86588 ,  333.23834 ,  438.0203  ,
                    581.85345 ,  339.57266 ,  457.12305 ,  320.24927 ,    0.      ,
                    354.19998 ,  515.85205 ,  421.9343  ,  352.8753  ,  294.42746 ,
                    612.50476 ,  287.2488  ,  514.80835 ,  317.7338  , 2197.196   ,
                    412.9734  ],
                  [ 456.45532 ,  299.7252  ,  233.60907 ,  534.6004  ,  226.06946 ,
                    545.06934 ,  233.96426 ,  214.50896 ,   94.12929 ,  267.78806 ,
                    281.4427  ,   65.66601 ,  401.13135 ,  413.39264 ,  412.9242  ,
                      0.      ,  414.6986  ,  525.05096 ,  288.66278 ,  246.21217 ,
                    453.87292 ,  246.21217 ,  198.48744 ,  577.5303  , 2243.206   ,
                    640.5496  ],
                  [ 155.05891 ,  568.0132  ,  202.34547 ,  523.2096  ,  209.78374 ,
                    599.26495 ,  198.99548 ,  324.08633 ,  360.44186 ,  440.45587 ,
                    204.37946 ,  347.49423 ,  550.2359  ,  487.60785 ,  499.01086 ,
                    348.1288  ,    0.      ,  540.9888  ,  135.66075 ,  382.7744  ,
                    152.5354  ,  388.61807 ,  340.47018 ,  605.20166 , 2219.416   ,
                    750.00006 ],
                  [ 485.56516 ,  599.9722  ,  555.8168  ,  433.31882 ,  546.8365  ,
                    387.8317  ,  568.41846 ,  355.81543 ,  380.595   ,  493.46066 ,
                    546.05084 ,  387.7209  ,  618.6706  ,  558.7649  ,  324.0919  ,
                    458.19125 ,  480.57907 ,    0.      ,  357.47806 ,  398.37247 ,
                    483.3039  ,  414.2812  ,  564.6456  ,  396.15234 , 2270.4104  ,
                    506.2483  ],
                  [ 258.69937 ,  363.43213 ,  254.57268 ,  486.9452  ,  260.889   ,
                    494.29837 ,  253.17126 ,  210.97049 ,  234.34555 ,  292.24005 ,
                    293.57297 ,  252.55754 ,  421.17807 ,  378.61005 ,  303.36768 ,
                    257.93448 ,  122.264015,  454.98428 ,    0.      ,  236.93938 ,
                    253.4676  ,  250.04745 ,  319.4175  ,  510.46442 , 2382.3901  ,
                    589.0268  ],
                  [ 505.6519  ,  319.01617 ,  369.75504 ,  347.82373 ,  354.70322 ,
                    460.26096 ,  369.75504 ,   69.547066,  127.82035 ,  210.15347 ,
                    426.0753  ,  159.16548 ,  322.0247  ,  289.36023 ,  302.46762 ,
                    212.24222 ,  382.88596 ,  438.27753 ,  247.4827  ,    0.      ,
                    485.8731  ,   57.478493,  295.67023 ,  473.18552 , 2146.8052  ,
                    597.9801  ],
                  [  52.440372,  623.14404 ,  302.80176 ,  624.6241  ,  293.33078 ,
                    709.0436  ,  276.45862 ,  508.44223 ,  503.47537 ,  551.4158  ,
                    235.32637 ,  443.49643 ,  625.1005  ,  617.32056 ,  600.292   ,
                    424.56824 ,  151.66562 ,  588.89496 ,  282.82944 ,  527.02325 ,
                      0.      ,  527.02325 ,  402.1343  ,  694.4563  , 2189.2695  ,
                    894.13544 ],
                  [ 505.6519  ,  314.47266 ,  369.75504 ,  347.82556 ,  354.70322 ,
                    455.94913 ,  360.55518 ,   70.66477 ,  133.36484 ,  210.88097 ,
                    421.11978 ,  172.64131 ,  309.93774 ,  274.33762 ,  301.96918 ,
                    211.38991 ,  380.6542  ,  438.65326 ,  247.4827  ,   57.478493,
                    518.7389  ,    0.      ,  298.9216  ,  473.18552 , 2146.8052  ,
                    575.477   ],
                  [ 414.08194 ,  201.07932 ,  199.54063 ,  494.52237 ,  199.88744 ,
                    575.1419  ,  216.00842 ,  267.15692 ,  267.73367 ,  211.15106 ,
                    246.80675 ,  238.4922  ,  328.6415  ,  317.64835 ,  520.3694  ,
                    200.55713 ,  398.5762  ,  555.1304  ,  321.4037  ,  332.76724 ,
                    418.20874 ,  324.56873 ,    0.      ,  612.2203  , 2017.541   ,
                    717.155   ],
                  [ 671.4406  ,  516.2827  ,  539.4914  ,  222.72615 ,  590.8812  ,
                    160.31212 ,  556.17993 ,  382.5772  ,  400.06876 ,  412.24472 ,
                    644.9995  ,  416.24802 ,  467.7319  ,  327.4732  ,  239.71906 ,
                    418.28366 ,  621.23175 ,  450.61893 ,  454.04272 ,  412.1341  ,
                    658.5174  ,  405.12924 ,  459.46152 ,    0.      , 2095.0942  ,
                    272.13074 ],
                  [1573.2515  , 1987.4009  , 1665.257   , 1870.9703  , 1826.2843  ,
                  1671.1206  , 1665.257   , 1911.0514  , 1910.6981  , 1910.8704  ,
                  1594.4753  , 1851.5399  , 1861.7765  , 1802.8763  , 1727.6866  ,
                  1944.2445  , 1632.5803  , 1619.3777  , 1871.582   , 1743.7849  ,
                  1609.6631  , 1795.7052  , 1948.1182  , 1791.7504  ,    0.      ,
                  2547.5269  ],
                  [ 829.8453  ,  676.68646 ,  670.7141  ,  273.16794 ,  708.10034 ,
                    239.30353 ,  655.7406  ,  561.3706  ,  605.7688  ,  578.7432  ,
                    804.855   ,  595.2515  ,  508.47095 ,  415.9521  ,  402.31876 ,
                    580.0205  ,  773.40485 ,  571.7874  ,  623.5673  ,  551.49817 ,
                    821.65045 ,  555.5913  ,  675.1111  ,  362.9447  , 2355.539   ,
                      0.      ]], dtype=float32)
```

Then I draw [the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmisD.png) on the map, and it looks strange. The pink icon is the start and the green icon is the end.

Did I do something wrong during the process?

Comment: Without explicitly controlling "node-drops" through disjunctions, the solver generates a hamiltonian-cycle/path visiting all nodes! I'm not sure what you expect as i don't see why someone would solve a single-source single-target SP problem with this solver. Even if you control drops, with the current code you would achieve a greedy-solution with (probably) one round of hill-climbing like local-search (as you did not enable metaheuristics). So... imho a very strange use-case.A trivial tractable problem tackled by an (incomplete) solver optimized for non-trivial / generally intractable problems